# Cannot add CSS to ExtJS' propertygrid's column

Tags: javascript, css, extjs

I found some answers on how to apply **css** to a **grid**, but none of them helped me in my case.
Here are the links I looked at:

1. http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?109751-Add-color-to-column-property-grid
2. [How to apply background color (or custom css class) to column in grid - ExtJs 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6673573/how-to-apply-background-color-or-custom-css-class-to-column-in-grid-extjs-4)
3. [How can I change the row colour in datagrid based on severity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5000554/how-can-i-change-the-row-colour-in-datagrid-based-on-severity)

Look at this simple example from **[Sencha](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.grid.property.Grid)**:

```
Ext.create('Ext.grid.property.Grid', {
    title: 'Properties Grid',
    width: 300,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    source: {
        "(name)": "My Object",
        "Created": Ext.Date.parse('10/15/2006', 'm/d/Y'),
        "Available": false,
        "Version": 0.01,
        "Description": "A test object"
    }
});
```

**I am trying to change "name" column's background color and some text formatting. How?**

I know hot to get to the column to change it size, but css is not working:

```
listeners : {
    beforerender : function() {
        var cols = this.getView().getHeaderCt().getGridColumns();
        cols[0].setText("Property");
        cols[0].setWidth(150);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

s. roma

I'm quite an extjs-rookie, but what's about the column-cls: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.grid.column.Column-cfg-cls

afaik you should be able to apply your style there

Comment: I have seen it, but can you give me an example based on what I asked?

Comment: sorry, maybe a stupid question, but do you want to change the whole COLUMN where 'name' is located, or do you want do chang the CELL?

Comment: The whole column, I want to give the user illusion that the whole left column is non-editable. Also maybe change the text color to black and style to bold.